# Changing scaffolding file names in Angular after project generation

Tags: angular

new to Angular 6. if after project generation, can the file names for the following standard files be changed to anything without it effecting future dependencies? If so, which scaffolding files need to be edited?

1. runtime.js
2. polyfills.js
3. styles.js
4. main.js

These files show up on the deployment index.html code and i dont want them to have standard names as shown below. There are several places that reference these files in scaffolding files and im wondering if there is a quick way to change them without going through each and every reference to them which seem like a lot?
Thank you!

Tried already editing files and it seems too tedious.

````
    <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>```

What I would like to see for example: 

```<app-root></app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="newfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="designs.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="other.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="important.js"></script></body>```
````